# How to copy a partitioned table to another partitioned table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to copy one partitioned table into another one. According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#copying_partitioned_tables), this should be possible.

> If you want to copy a partitioned table into another partitioned table, the partition specifications for the source and destination tables must match.

To test, I created two partitioned tables (`partition1` & `partition2`) with the same schema. I pushed 3 records into partition `$20170101` on the `partition1` table:

```
echo '{"a":1, "b":2}' | bq insert '<removed>.partition1$20170101'
echo '{"a":1, "b":2}' | bq insert '<removed>.partition1$20170101'
echo '{"a":1, "b":2}' | bq insert '<removed>.partition1$20170101'
```

That looks good:

[image]

Next, I pushed 2 records into the `partition2` table and to the same partition (`$20170101`):

```
echo '{"a":1, "b":2}' | bq insert '<removed>.partition2$20170101'
echo '{"a":1, "b":2}' | bq insert '<removed>.partition2$20170101'
```

Again, this looks good:

[image]

Now, I want to copy append `partition2` into `partition1`. I would expect to see 5 records in `partition1` under the `$20170101` partition:

```
bq cp --append_table <removed>.partition2 <removed>.partition1
Waiting on bqjob_r6d160e17a3b7b733_0000015bb238aa54_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
Tables '<removed>.partition2' successfully copied to '<removed>.partition1'
```

However, `partition1` still only has 3 records in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot confirm this behavior! I just did all exactly the same steps you described (but in UI) and got expected result - 5 records. Can  you double check if you do all as you described?

Comment: How did you copy in the UI?. It doesn't allow it if the table already exist. It has to be done via the API...

Comment: good point. I am not using Google Web UI. The UI that we are using implements all via API calls  - so technically it was via API. but it shouldn't matter for the issue you raised, I think. Unless it is an issue with bq command line tool

Comment: I used the CLI tool - `bq cp --append_table <removed>.partition2 <removed>.partition1` - it definitely does not work. I triple checked.

Comment: yes, i got it. I mentioned in my last comment that it is potentially the issue with bq cli

Comment: i didn't even know that Google Web UI does not allow to copy with append into existing table. I am using it a lot but with another UI.

Comment: Yeah, it does not give the option to overwrite/append and just returns a "duplicate error" if the table already exists.

Comment: yes, i just checked. that's weird. in our UI implementation we support almost all available API features so I was lucky enough to not even know about this

Comment: It must be a problem with the CLI tool. I'll try an update..

Comment: Yup, that was it. I updated the CLI tool and it seems to be working now.

Comment: super! :o) thank you for update

Comment: Thanks for hints to look at the CLI Mikhail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the version of the `gcloud` tool I had installed. I updated it, and then it worked as expected.

Run:

`gcloud components update`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the command something like this from gcloud and it works -->

```
bq cp -a '<source_project>:<source_dataset>.<source_table>$20180605' <destination_project>:<destination_dataset>.<destination_table>
```

and it works perfiectly fine....
Note:- In the command above , destination partition value/information need not be mentioned. It automatically fetches from source partition data/value.